# AVAudioPlayer only plays part of sound

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play a song clip when a button is pressed using AVAudioPlayer. The whole clip plays fine in Xcode, but when I load the app on a device and press the button it plays the first second of the song and then goes quiet.

I have this under viewDidLoad:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Song.aiff", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&audioFileError];
player.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

And then this when the button is pressed:

```
if (player == nil)
    NSLog(@"Audio file could not be played");
else
    [player play];
```

Edit: I am also open to other suggestions as to how to play the audio clip, AVAudioPlayer just seemed like the easiest and most straightforward way to do so.

Comment: That could mean the player is being released prematurely.

Comment: Does it fades out or come to an abrupt stop? If it fades out properly, it could mean that you have an audio interrupt

Comment: I'm using ARC, would that still happen? And if so how do I keep it from doing so?

Comment: Seems like it's just coming to an abrupt stop.

Comment: Ensure that your AVAudioPlayer is properly retained and synthesized.  Also, the audiofile may have gotten corrupted, so you might want to check that.

Comment: It's retained and synthesized. And like I said it plays with no problem in Xcode and iTunes, so I don't think it's corrupted.

Comment: Try logging the players error property and see if it outputs anything.

Comment: The audioFileError? Just did that, no output related to that.

Comment: Call prepareToPlay after you instantiate the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it thanks to 8vius, put in

```
[player prepareToPlay];
```

after the numberOfLoops line and it works like a charm.

Comment: Was about to add the answer, glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing this after you instantiate the AVAudioPlayer:

```
[self.player prepareToPlay];
```

This method prepares the buffers for playback.

Also use `self` when referring to your variables, that way you are accessing the instance variables properly through your accessor methods and not the ivar directly.